# Trying to blur UITableView behind UIAlertController over UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I want to blur my `UITableView` (inside a `UITableViewController`) when I present a `UIAlertController` (`UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`) but when using `UIBlurEffect` and `UIVisualEffectView` it doesn't blur the table view's content behind it; it just blocks it out. Happens on both simulator and device.

```
- (void)showAlert {
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Alert Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        // handle choice...

        [visualEffectView removeFromSuperview];
    }]];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        // handle choice...

        [visualEffectView removeFromSuperview];
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

There is text content in the table view behind the action sheet that ought to be showing up as blurred, e.g. like in this image:

[image]

Comment: Can you try visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds; ?

Comment: Tried that already. Doesn't make a difference

Comment: Tested things out and it seems that `UIBlurEffect` doesn't work particularly well with text anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried on view and it works fine. I have made few changes in your code.

```
 - (void)showAlert {
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];

    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    //self.vBlur.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Alert Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        // handle choice...

        [visualEffectView removeFromSuperview];
    }]];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        // handle choice...

        [visualEffectView removeFromSuperview];
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: another screenshot?]

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't look fine to me.

Comment: why? What's wrong into it?
You want it full screen?

Comment: Does that look blurred to you? It's just a solid dark grey background behind the action sheet.

Comment: If you change anything in uiblureffect enum like UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight still you will not see a complete blur effect.

Comment: There is no blur effect working at all here, regardless of the enum choice. That's a solid background, just like mine.

Comment: @shim got it. I have just changed one line in my code and it works fine.             [self.vBlur addSubview:visualEffectView]; I have added visualeffectview instance in a view.

Comment: What is `self.vBlur`?

Comment: In main view of uiviewcontroller i have added another view named as "vBlur" and then i have added visualeffectview to it. So that whatever controls i have added in main view will get blur.

Comment: Update your screenshot?

Comment: i have added a new answer with two screenshots. have a look.

Comment: None of them look blurred to me. And you shouldn't add a separate answer with just links to images.